# jQuery quick filter issue with searching span title attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on the jQuery Quick Filter (https://github.com/syropian/jQuery-Quick-Filter) and am having trouble getting the filter to filter using the span title attributes.

I changed the github code to allow it to also search by the title attribute by adding in the `elem.title` parts to the code.

This snippet demonstrates the issue:

```js
/*
 * Plugin Name: QuickFilter
 * Author: Collin Henderson (collin@syropia.net)
 * Version: 1.0
 * © 2012, http://syropia.net
 * You are welcome to freely use and modify this script in your personal and commercial products. Please don't sell it or release it as your own work. Thanks!
 * https://github.com/syropian/jQuery-Quick-Filter
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42530073/jquery-search-image-title-attribute
 */
(function($) {
  $.extend($.expr[':'], {
    missing: function(elem, index, match) {
      return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || elem.title || "").toLowerCase().indexOf(match[3]) == -1;
    }
  });
  $.extend($.expr[':'], {
    exists: function(elem, i, match, array) {
      return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || elem.title || '').toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    }
  });
  $.extend($.fn, {
    quickfilter: function(el) {
      return this.each(function() {
        var _this = $(this);
        var query = _this.val().toLowerCase();
        _this.keyup(function() {
          query = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
          if (query.replace(/\s/g, "") != "") {
            $(el + ':exists("' + query.toString() + '")').show();
            $(el + ':missing("' + query.toString() + '")').hide();
          } else {
            $(el).show();
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);



$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#txtSearch').quickfilter('#list li');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="txtSearch" placeholder="filter" class="form-control" />

<ul id="list" class="list-group list-group-flush">
 <li class="list-group-item" title="banana 1f34c - "></li>
 <li class="list-group-item" title="kiwi fruit 1f95d - ">testing </li>
 <li class="list-group-item" title="carrots 1f955 - "><img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/svg/1f955.svg" style="width:30px; height:30px"> carrot</li>
 <li class="list-group-item" title="bacon 1f953 "><img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/svg/1f953.svg" style="width:30px; height:30px"></li>
 <li class="list-group-item" title="cucumber 1f952 "><img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/svg/1f952.svg" style="width:30px; height:30px"> now I can't filter on title attribute but I can search on text between span tags</li>
</ul>
```

The issue being that sometimes I can filter on the title attributes, but other times I can only filter on the content between the span tags rather than the title attribute of the span element.

1. For the first item, for the banana, I can paste in the  emoji and it filters on that, but will not filter on the word `banana` even though that appears in the title attribute.
2. For the second item, I can search by either `testing` or the  emoji, but I cannot filter on the word `kiwi` or `fruit` even though they appear in the title attribute.
3. For the third item, I can filter on the word `carrot`(which is between the span tags), but not on the word `carrots` which appears in the title attributes.
4. For the fourth item, I now can search on the title attributes, so can type bacon and it works...
5. For the fifth item - because there is now text in between the span tags, I cannot search on the title attributes, but can search on the text between the span tags.

   I wondered how I can get this to work, so the filter checks the content of the title attribute - but also the content between the span tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by combining all of the strings into one and using indexOf against the entire string instead of using || (or) in both **missing** and **existing**.

```js
/*
 * Plugin Name: QuickFilter
 * Author: Collin Henderson (collin@syropia.net)
 * Version: 1.0
 * © 2012, http://syropia.net
 * You are welcome to freely use and modify this script in your personal and commercial products. Please don't sell it or release it as your own work. Thanks!
 * https://github.com/syropian/jQuery-Quick-Filter
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42530073/jquery-search-image-title-attribute
 */
(function($) {
  $.extend($.expr[':'], {
    missing: function(elem, index, match) {
      return (elem.textContent + elem.innerText + elem.title + "").toLowerCase().indexOf(match[3]) == -1;
    }
  });
  $.extend($.expr[':'], {
    exists: function(elem, i, match, array) {
      return (elem.textContent + elem.innerText + elem.title + '').toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    }
  });
  $.extend($.fn, {
    quickfilter: function(el) {
      return this.each(function() {
        var _this = $(this);
        var query = _this.val().toLowerCase();
        _this.keyup(function() {
          query = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
          if (query.replace(/\s/g, "") != "") {
            $(el + ':exists("' + query.toString() + '")').show();
            $(el + ':missing("' + query.toString() + '")').hide();
          } else {
            $(el).show();
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);



$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#txtSearch').quickfilter('#list li');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="txtSearch" placeholder="filter" class="form-control" />

<ul id="list" class="list-group list-group-flush">
 <li class="list-group-item" title="banana 1f34c - "></li>
 <li class="list-group-item" title="kiwi fruit 1f95d - ">testing </li>
 <li class="list-group-item" title="carrots 1f955 - "><img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/svg/1f955.svg" style="width:30px; height:30px"> carrot</li>
 <li class="list-group-item" title="bacon 1f953 "><img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/svg/1f953.svg" style="width:30px; height:30px"></li>
 <li class="list-group-item" title="cucumber 1f952 "><img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/svg/1f952.svg" style="width:30px; height:30px"> now I can't filter on title attribute but I can search on text between span tags</li>
</ul>
```