# Filter elements by title attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a solution from SO - [jQuery - Search image title attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42530073/jquery-search-image-title-attribute/42531782#42531782).

This is a demo of that solution:

```js
/*
 * Plugin Name: QuickFilter
 * Author: Collin Henderson (collin@syropia.net)
 * Version: 1.0
 * © 2012, http://syropia.net
 * You are welcome to freely use and modify this script in your personal and commercial products. Please don't sell it or release it as your own work. Thanks!
 * Seach images by title https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42530073/jquery-search-image-title-attribute/42531782#42531782
*/
(function($){
$.extend($.expr[':'], {missing: function (elem, index, match) {
 return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || elem.title || "").toLowerCase().indexOf(match[3]) == -1;
}});
$.extend($.expr[':'], {exists: function(elem, i, match, array){
 return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || elem.title || '').toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
}});
$.extend($.fn,{
 quickfilter: function(el){
   return this.each(function(){
   var _this = $(this);
   var query = _this.val().toLowerCase();
   _this.keyup(function () {
    query = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if(query.replace(/\s/g,"") != ""){
     $(el+':exists("' + query.toString() + '")').show();
     $(el+':missing("' + query.toString() + '")').hide();
    }
    else {
     $(el).show();
    }
   });
  });
 }
});
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#txtSearch').quickfilter('#list img');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">

 <div id="list">
 <input id="txtSearch" placeholder="filter" style="border:1px solid silver; display:block; margin:5px;" type="text">
  <img title="grapes" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/svg/1f347.svg" style="width:30px; height:30px">
  <img title="watermelon" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/svg/1f349.svg" style="width:30px; height:30px">
  <img title="tangerine" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/svg/1f34a.svg" style="width:30px; height:30px">
  <img title="lemon" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/svg/1f34b.svg" style="width:30px; height:30px">
  <img title="banana" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/svg/1f34c.svg" style="width:30px; height:30px">
 </div>
    
</div>
```

This solution works perfectly for searching images based on their title attribute - as the title of the SO question states.

I'd like to be able to search based on the title attribute of a `span` element - e.g.

```
<div id="listnature">
    <input type="text" id="txtSearchnature" placeholder="Filter Animals & Nature" class="form-control" />
    <span title="monkey face - "></span>
    <span title="monkey - "></span>
    <span title="gorilla - "></span>
    <span title="dog face - "></span>
    <span title="dog - "></span>
    <span title="poodle - "></span>
    <span title="wolf face - "></span>
</div>
```

With the relevant JS changed to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#txtSearchnature').quickfilter('#listnature span');
});
```

However - the filter does not work because the JS is based on the solution for filtering based on an image's title attribute - in this case I'd like to filter on the span's title attribute.

I wondered if it would be possible to change the JS to achieve that result?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in this line

```
return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || elem.title || "")
```

where it says:

get `textContent`, if that's empty, get `innerText`, if that's empty, get `title`, otherwise give empty string.

The difference between `span` and `img` is that `span` has a `textContent` so it gives the `textContent` (the unicode image) and attempts to match that - which fails.

If you wish to match on the title first, you can change the order of checks:

```
return (elem.title || elem.textContent || elem.innerText || "")
```

You'll need to do this twice, once for `:missing` and once for `:exists` - of course you only actually need one of these and hide/show by default.

Updated code:

```js
/*
 * Plugin Name: QuickFilter
 * Author: Collin Henderson (collin@syropia.net)
 * Version: 1.0
 * © 2012, http://syropia.net
 * You are welcome to freely use and modify this script in your personal and commercial products. Please don't sell it or release it as your own work. Thanks!
 * Seach images by title https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42530073/jquery-search-image-title-attribute/42531782#42531782
*/
(function($){
$.extend($.expr[':'], {missing: function (elem, index, match) {
 return (elem.title || elem.textContent || elem.innerText || "").toLowerCase().indexOf(match[3]) == -1;
}});
$.extend($.expr[':'], {exists: function(elem, i, match, array){
 return (elem.title || elem.textContent || elem.innerText || '').toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
}});
$.extend($.fn,{
 quickfilter: function(el){
   return this.each(function(){
   var _this = $(this);
   var query = _this.val().toLowerCase();
   _this.keyup(function () {
    query = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if(query.replace(/\s/g,"") != ""){
     $(el+':exists("' + query.toString() + '")').show();
     $(el+':missing("' + query.toString() + '")').hide();
    }
    else {
     $(el).show();
    }
   });
  });
 }
});
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#txtSearchnature').quickfilter('#listnature span');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="listnature">
    <input type="text" id="txtSearchnature" placeholder="Filter Animals & Nature" class="form-control" />
    <span title="monkey face - "></span>
    <span title="monkey - "></span>
    <span title="gorilla - "></span>
    <span title="dog face - "></span>
    <span title="dog - "></span>
    <span title="poodle - "></span>
    <span title="wolf face - "></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it given the `title` attribute more priority changing next code:

```
(elem.textContent || elem.innerText || elem.title || "")
```

by

```
(elemt.title || elem.textContent || elem.innerText || "")
```

or by this, if you are only interested on filter by the title

```
(elemt.title || "")
```

on the definitions of the new **missing** and **exists** pesudo-classes.

**Example of fixed code:**

```js
/*
 * Plugin Name: QuickFilter
 * Author: Collin Henderson (collin@syropia.net)
 * Version: 1.0
 * © 2012, http://syropia.net
 * You are welcome to freely use and modify this script in your personal and commercial products. Please don't sell it or release it as your own work. Thanks!
 * Seach images by title https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42530073/jquery-search-image-title-attribute/42531782#42531782
*/
(function($)
{
  $.extend($.expr[':'], {missing: function(elem, index, match)
  {
      return (elem.title || elem.textContent || elem.innerText || "").toLowerCase().indexOf(match[3]) == -1;
  }});

  $.extend($.expr[':'], {exists: function(elem, i, match, array)
  {
      return (elem.title || elem.textContent || elem.innerText || '').toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
  }});

  $.extend($.fn, {quickfilter: function(el)
  {
      return this.each(function()
      {
          var _this = $(this);
          var query = _this.val().toLowerCase();

          _this.keyup(function()
          {
              query = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

              if (query.replace(/\s/g,"") != "") {
                  $(el+':exists("' + query.toString() + '")').show();
                  $(el+':missing("' + query.toString() + '")').hide();
              }
              else {
                  $(el).show();
              }
          });
      });
  }});
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#txtSearchnature').quickfilter('#listnature span');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="listnature">
    <input type="text" id="txtSearchnature" placeholder="Filter Animals & Nature" class="form-control" />
    <span title="monkey face - "></span>
    <span title="monkey - "></span>
    <span title="gorilla - "></span>
    <span title="dog face - "></span>
    <span title="dog - "></span>
    <span title="poodle - "></span>
    <span title="wolf face - "></span>
</div>
```